# Leaflet.Spin for Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, typescript, leaflet, spinner, ionic4

I currently have a leaflet map for my Ionic 4 app, it is currently working. I would like to use the leaflet.spin plugin to show when data is being returned by an API and then display the data on the leaflet map. I really don't know to set the plugin up for Ionic 4.

The map.spin(true); and map.spin(false); is all I want to add in before  the data receiving, formatting and and after displaying the data on the map.

I have tried just adding an import and a require but I'm really not sure how to use the leaflet.spin plugin with leaflet and the map that is already made.

Thanks for reading, and would love to hear back :)